# asp.net unhandled exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

I have an application that has been running in produciton for a while now, and every now and then it throws an akward exception that I catch in the global.asax session error event. This procedure sends an email out with the error message, source, and stack of the error, and that is usually sufficient information for us to find the problem. However, this particular error does not have the entire stack. It apparently dies before it gets to my application in the stack.

Below is the information that is sent to me in an email. Through some other logging within my application, I can find which page it is occuring, but without the stack showing any of my application's code, I really don't know where to start. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Error Info:

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source: System.Web

Stack:

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Interesting indeed! If you know which page it's on, can you examine the event handlers of any image buttons you have on that page?

Answer (score 1):

Are there any complaining users?

Wouldn't bother otherwise-- this might be triggered by a robot browser, or a user cancelling his request at an unexpected point, and many other reasons.

Comment: This should not be robot. There is a user that is logged when this is happening. The users that would be complaining are our customers. We do not want them to complain, and we do not want them to see error screens.

Comment: We had a similiar issue a couple of years ago. I talked to many users about it, and they all said they had never seen the error screen.  So not every thrown error ends up as an error message in a user's browser.  (Yours might be, of course.)

Comment: I have actually looked in the IIS logs to see if the error page was loaded and found that there were hits on it when this error message was sent.

Answer (score 0):

I would start looking at the page that threw the error, then look at the various image button controls that you have.  My guess would be a dynamically loaded control, that was not reloaded.

We can't say much until we see the code

Comment: I think that is the problem, he does not know which page is throwing the exception.

Comment: @mxmissile - he noted in the post that he can find the page in question.

Comment: this is hard to pin down. the problem is happening on multiple pages that are structured quite a bit different. it would appear that they all have dynamic data though.